# Difference between Thread(method) and Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(method))

Tags: .net, multithreading

Whats the difference between the below two pieces of code?

```
Foo parameter = // get parameter value
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod));
thread.Start(parameter);
```

```
Foo parameter = // get parameter value
Thread thread = new Thread(DoMethod);
thread.Start(parameter);
```

```
private void DoMethod(object obj)
{
    Foo parameter = (Foo)obj;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was voted "off-topic"... If this question is not on-topic on SO, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference. The compiler implicitly converts `new Thread(DoMethod)` to `new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoMethod))`. Implicit conversion of a method group to a delegate with a compatible signature was introduced in C# 2; before that, you had to use the explicit form.